# Test promise-chain with Jest

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I'm trying to test promises-chain sequence with Jest:

```
someChainPromisesMethod: function() {
    async()
      .then(async1)
      .then(async2)
      .then(result)
      .catch(error);
}
```

While testing single promise is good documented not sure what is a proper way (not sure what to do TBO) to test this kind of chain. Let's assume all asyncs are mocked and just resolves promises (Promise.resolve) in theirs body.

So I need something that will test whole sequence.

Comment: The method should `return` the promise it creates

Comment: What exactly do you want to test for? Getting `result` called? Expect a return value from the `result`? Expect errors to be caught?

Comment: I want to test sunny-day scenario with all sequence to be called (resolved) and the values on each next call.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [jest.fn()](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#jest-fn-implementation) to mock implementation and check what the function has been called with and return what you want. You need to mock all `async` functions you have in your function and return what you want.

e.g.

```
async = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('value');
});

async1 = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('value1');
});

async2 = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('Final Value');
});
```

You can use this in your test as

```
it('should your test scenario', (done) => {
  someChainPromisesMethod()
    .then(data => {
      expect(async1).toBeCalledWith('value');
      expect(async2).toBeCalledWith('value1');
      expect(data).toEqual('Final Value');
      done(); 
  });
});
```

However, I would flatten your chain and test them separately if you have logic in them, that way you can test all possibilities easily.

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 5):

Using done does not fix the issue, it will give you a false positive test. If for any reason an expectation fails, your test will timeout and you'll not have the real result.

The right solution is to return your Promise, so Jest will be able to evaluate the expect result correctly.

Following the @grgmo example, a better approach could be:

```
it('should your test scenario', () => {
  return someChainPromisesMethod()
    .then(data => {
      expect(async1).toBeCalledWith('value');
      expect(async2).toBeCalledWith('value1');
      expect(data).toEqual('Final Value');
  });
});
```